# How can I access the sequence data from a form?

Tags: javascript, html, json

The HTML code the JSON array is populated from:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> <label> Did you like this presentation?</label> </td>
        <td>
            <select id="Q181" onchange="window.parent.addDataFromElement(this[this.selectedIndex])">
                <option id="R201" value="R201">Yes</option> 
                <option id="R202" value="R202">No</option> 
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <label>Could you please give us your opinion?</label> </td>
        <td> <input type="text" id="Q183" onchange="window.parent.addData(this.id,this.value)"/> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <label id="Q184">Are you satisfied?</label> </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="R203" value="R203" onclick="window.parent.addDataFromElement(this)">Yes</input><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="R204" value="R204" onclick="window.parent.addDataFromElement(this)">No</input>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <label>Give a rating from 1 to 5</label> </td>
        <td> <input type="number" max="5" min="1" id="Q185" onchange="window.parent.addDataFromElement(this)"/> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The code that obtains data :

```
<span class='template' data-template='${context.presentations[0].sequences[6].data[0].value}'></span>
```

The error message is :
`error during template : TypeError: context.presentations[0].sequences[6] is undefined`

How do I access the `sequences`?

Comment: ok thank you it's my first question

Comment: No problem. As a guidance, please invest a bit of time to study how to post a good question. Start wiith [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: thank you this is helpful for me

Comment: Your code sample is incomplete. How does the JSON array look like?

Comment: In this [Guide line page 18](http://www.unicef.pt/siria/HTML5PresentationCreation.pdf)